# RelativeLayout inside a ScrollView not working with Landscape Orientation

Tags: android, landscape-portrait, android-scrollview

I need to have multiple textviews within a scrollview. I am using a relative layout as a container to all these textviews.

The layout looks fine in portrait orientation, but when in landscape orientation, the textview at the top of the relative layout within the scrollview (tvEx) is not visible. This is only when I test in the emulator for devices that have a small screen. Apart from this minor problem, the layout works perfectly well. Although, this seems to be a minor issue, somehow I am not able to get around it. Kindly help.

The layout file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/Header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/header" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btBack"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvBanner"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btBack"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btBack"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:gravity="fill"
            android:text="Practice Exam"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/footer"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btHome"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/home" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Header"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:gravity="center" >


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvEx"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:text="Congratulations!!"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="24sp"/>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvRes"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvEx"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="You passed"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvLuck"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvRes"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Great going"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lins"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvLuck"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvScore"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="SCORE:"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvScoreNum"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvScore"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tvScore"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvCorr"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lins"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Correct Answers:"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvIncorr"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvCorr"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Incorrect Answers:"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvtot"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvIncorr"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Total Questions:"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in a `ScrollView`. Try changing `android:gravity="center"` to `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` or removing it completely. Similar to [ScrollView hides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293349/scrollview-object-hides).